# A/B testing across wizard like page flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ab-testing

I run this website http://www.gipote.dk where users can create ads to sell dogs, puppies and equipment for pets.

The ad-creation process is a wizard-like flow over multiple pages.

I want to change this wizard in several ways - not just the content, but the order of the pages - and want to A/B test the outcoming results.

The flow can end up in one of the following results:

- No ad is created (the user aborts - we don't like that... ;-)
- A "Standard-Ad" is created
- A "Silver-Ad" is created
- A "Gold-Ad" is created

Since we already use Google Analytics, I thought about using their "Content Experiment" module for this testing, but it seems to be for testing only 1 page's content at a time.

Any thoughts about how this could be accomplished? In GA or with another tool?

Bonus info: The site is created in Rails 3.0

I **will** be able to send the user to different ending-page-urls based on the type of Ad created.

The start urls will probably be:

**www.gipote.dk/annonce/new** (this is the current version)

**www.gipote.dk/annonce2/new** (the new version - a complete new controller)

/ Carsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are gems to make this easy for you. See Ryan Bates's screencasts on Split and A/Bingo.

Links:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/214-a-b-testing-with-a-bingo

and

http://railscasts.com/episodes/331-a-b-testing-with-split

Comment: I've already looked at Abingo. But as I read it, it's used for split testning of a single view. I need to split test an entire flow.

Answer (score 1):

I've just open-sourced an integration with the Google Analytics Experiments API for Rails.  Take a look - hopefully it'll do what you need.  It does keep the user in a persistent group by using Rails.cache.

https://github.com/dlangevin/gxapi_rails